# Meteor server side call to Ethereum node

Tags: meteor, ethereum

I try to interact with Ethereum node via web3 lib. (meteor add ethereum:web3)

Meteor 1.5.4.1

lib.js:

```
if (typeof web3 === ‘undefined’){
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(‘http://127.0.0.1:21045’));
```

}

main.js:

---

```
web3.eth.defaultContractEvent = “0x*************************************”;
contract_event = web3.eth.contract(abi_event).at(web3.eth.defaultContractEvent);
 var events = contract_event.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: ‘latest’});
```

---

get error at last line

```
C:\Users***\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.2_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
 throw(ex);
 ^

TypeError: XHR2 is not a function
 at [object Object].HttpProvider.prepareRequest (packages\ethereum_web3.js:4315:15)
 at [object Object].HttpProvider.sendAsync (packages\ethereum_web3.js:4364:22)
 at [object Object].RequestManager.sendAsync (packages\ethereum_web3.js:6369:19)
 at Object.send [as newFilter] (packages\ethereum_web3.js:5080:42)
 at new Filter (packages\ethereum_web3.js:3568:25)
 at [object Object].AllSolidityEvents.execute (packages\ethereum_web3.js:2716:12)
at server/main.js:135:30

at Function.time (C:\***\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:309:28)
at C:\***\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:348:13
at C:\***\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:389:5
```

Exited with code: 1

what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is clear: `XHR2 is not a function`

Comment: this error is appear in
var events = contract_event.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: ‘latest’});

Comment: this error is appear in  string 
var events = contract_event.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: ‘latest’}); 
and problem is caused in web3 library. I m looking for method to solve problem